# Selective Merge/Conflict Resolution

Tags: git, merge, conflict

I'm involved in a fairly large project which has a lot of developers. For a certain feature development, a new branch was created (let's call this branch `feature_a`).

Now while trying to merge the `master` into `feature_a`, there are multiple conflicts in various "modules", where different developers are responsible for these modules.

How can I independently resolve conflicts in files I'm responsible for and leave the other files unmerged?

Comment: You can't leave the other files unmerged, you must commit something for those files.  In Git, a commit involves _every_ file in the repository.  The best you can probably hope for is collaborating with the other developers and do the merge together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite the history of `feature_a`, to split it in a list of commits where each commit is the responsibility of one single developper, then have each developper merge its "own" code back into `master`.

Here is an outline for this idea :

```
# from branch feature_a :

# create a new branch :
$ git checkout -b merge_feature_a

# find commit where it forked from `master` :
$ git merge-base master feature_1
0125638

# reset current merge_feature_a to this commit :
$ git reset 0125638

# diff feature_a and merge-base to get the full list of modified files :
$ git diff --name-only 0125638 feature_a

# create first commit with files which are Mike's responsibility :
$ git add <files for Mike>
$ git commit -m "feature_a for Mike"

# same for Sally :
$ git add <files for Sally>
$ git commit -m "feature_a for Sally"

# etc ...

# push this new branch :
$ git push origin merge_feature_a

# tell Mike to merge first commit,
# when he's done tell Sally to merge second commit,
# etc ...
```

What you get this way is a sequence of merge commits, where the end result is (hopefully) the content you wish for.

---

*Bonus points* : create a merge commit at the right spot in history

Once the merging process is completed, you can fiddle with the history, so that this content is shown as a commit joining both the orignal `master` branch and the original `feature_a` branch :

```
# from master :

# rewind master to its state before any merge :
# use '--soft' to keep every modifications in the index
#  (your next commit will have this content)
$ git reset --soft 1e67a9bb   # <- insert the hash of the original master

# get the sha1 of the commit for feature_a :
$ git rev-parse feature_a
e9573881e2eff04d219e57dfd4d7739aa5c11693

# write this hash into '.git/MERGE_HEAD' :
$ git rev-parse feature_a > .git/MERGE_HEAD

# commit : the presence of the MERGE_HEAD file indicates a merge commit
$ git commit
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking along the same lines but was hoping to avoid creating a new branch. Solves the problem though. Thank-you for taking the time to explain this in detail.